# java differ array into specific value

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to figure out how to differ array into specific value.

Let's assume the array is : `int [] A = {9, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 34, 53};`

And I have other two arrays which has empty value, let's say they are array B and C.

I have limit value t = 4;

So, I have to check value of array A.

If value of array A <= t, the value will be inserted to array B. If not, the value will be inserted to array C.

For example, from array A = {9, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 34, 53}

9, 5, 34, 53 must be inserted to B, so array B must be: `B = {9, 5, 34, 53};`

4, 3, 2, 1 must be inserted to C, so array C must be: `C = {4, 3, 2, 1};`

Below code is what I've tried:

```
public class splArray {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        int [] A = {9, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 34, 53};
        int [] B = new int[A.length];
        int [] C = new int[A.length];
        int t = 4;

        for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
            if(A[i] <= t){ 
                B[i] = A[i]; 
            } 
            else { 
                C[i] = A[i]; 
            } 
            System.out.println("B = "+ B[i]);
            //System.out.println("C = "+ C[i]); 
        }
    } 
}
```

Result:

```
B = 0
B = 0 
B = 4 
B = 3 
B = 2 
B = 1 
B = 0 
B = 0
```

The result doesn't meet what I expected. How can I solve this ?

**Edit:**

What I really expected: all zero values from B or C must be removed.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use same index for all arrays. Just push the values to the array without specifying an index. Here you go:

```
int j = 0; // For B
int k = 0; // For C

for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
    if(A[i] <= t) { 
        B[j] = A[i];
        j++;
    } else { 
        C[k] = A[i]; 
        k++;
    } 
}
```

But you should really use ArrayList because you don't know what size to allocate for arrays B and C. ArrayList will automatically expand whenever you need more space.

```
int [] A = {9, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 34, 53};
ArrayList<Integer> B = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> C = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int t = 4;

for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
    if(A[i] <= t) { 
        B.add(A[i]); 
    } else { 
        C.add(A[i]); 
    }  
}
```

Comment: is `push` part of `Array` or `List`?

Comment: Whoops - too much JavaScript for me ;) Fixed

Answer (score 2):

```
    public class splArray {
        public static void main(String [] args){
            int [] A = {9, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 34, 53};
            int t = 4;
            int count = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
                if(A[i] <= t){ 
                    count++; 
                }
            }
            int [] B = new int[count];
            int [] C = new int[A.length-count];


            for(int i = 0,j=0,k=0; i < A.length; i++){
                if(A[i] <= t){ 
                    B[j] = A[i]; 
                    System.out.println("B = "+ B[j]);
                    j++;
                } 
                else { 
                    C[k] = A[i];
                    System.out.println("C = "+ C[k]);
                    k++; 
                } 
            }
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `i` for all 3 arrays, you want to use separate indices for A, B and C.

```
        int j=0, k=0;
        for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
        if(A[i] <= t){ 
            B[j] = A[i]; 
            j++;
        } 
        else { 
            C[k] = A[i]; 
            k++;
        }
```

You also might consider something like an `ArrayList` rather than a static array, so that you have only as many elements as you want. Else, in your solution, the remaining slots will be filled with the default of 0.

To remove the trailing 0s, Finish the loop, then try

```
B = Arrays.copyOf(B, j+1);
```

Comment: @Speaky That 0 is because you have defined the arrays as being as long as B or C. You can either create new arrays that are exactly as long as you need (hint : `j+1`) or just use `ArrayList`

Answer (score 1):

Your program works fine but indexing needs to fix.. keep two counter to increamemnt for B and C and put debug outside of loop

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString( B));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString( C));
```

Your code's modified version should be like below where both B and C using different counter

```
public static void main(String [] args){
        int [] A = {9, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 34, 53};
        int [] B = new int[A.length];
        int [] C = new int[A.length];
        int t = 4;

        int countb = 0;
        int countc = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
            if(A[i] <= t){ 
                B[countb++] = A[i]; 
            } 
            else { 
                C[countc++] = A[i]; 
            } 

        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString( B));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString( C));
    }
```

Comment: Okay, it works.. But, what I need is to remove zero (0) from the B or C array.. How to do that?

Comment: better to use ArrayList instead of Arrays

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int [] A = {9, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 34, 53};
    int [] B = new int[A.length];
    int [] C = new int[A.length];
    int t = 4;
    int j=0,k=0;
    for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
        if(A[i] <= t){ 
            B[j] = A[i]; 
            j++;
        } 
        else { 
            C[k] = A[i]; 
            k++;
        } 

    }
    for(int i = 0; i < j; i++){
        System.out.println("B = "+ B[i]);

    }
    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++){

        System.out.println("C = "+ C[i]);
    }
}
```